# JSON data with node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, curl, http-post

I am new to node js programming and I've started developing RESTful API. Now, when I POST the data from terminal with curl like this:

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"full_name":"Hristijan ilieski", "email":"email@mail.com", "password":"123"}' http://localhost:3000/api/login

I am getting the right data in the request body.
But when I try to post some json from hurl.it or some other service, the request body is empty. What is the difference and where is the problem? Here's my code:

```
function registerUser(req, res){
var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
//jsonData['key'] should contain the value...
}
```

Here is an image from the hurl.it request:

[hurl request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJHVe.png)

**EDIT**

I don't know what I've done, but now when I try to POST a request from hurl.it, I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token f
>       at parse (/home/hristijan/Documents/UrbanAPI/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
>       at /home/hristijan/Documents/UrbanAPI/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
>       at invokeCallback (/home/hristijan/Documents/UrbanAPI/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
>       at done (/home/hristijan/Documents/UrbanAPI/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/hristijan/Documents/UrbanAPI/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
>       at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)

Comment: Did you set the header Content-Type:application/json in hurl.it? that might be the problem

Comment: Yes, I've set the Content-Type: application/json... I've even tried with some different services from hurl.it, but it doesn't work. It only works when I try to POST a request from curl..

Comment: Can you attach a print screen of your hurl.it request so I can see if there are any differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using the the hurl.it body instead of parameters like this:

[image]

The whole body is:

```
{
  "full_name":"Pero Perov",
  "email":"pero@mail.com",
  "password":"pero123",
  "mobile_number":"076 543 210",
  "home_address":"Perovaca 16b",
  "work_address":"Merovaca 18c"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you strinfigying then JSON.parsing the request body? That sends you back to square one...

Also, you might need some accept headers and utf-8 encoding, depending on how your backend is set up... (The latter has come back to haunt me before.)

Might want to try Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I was testing something and changed that to JSON.stringify...

Comment: I solve it with the help of the answer above this.. Thanks anyway.